# MVC Controller Error Messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC 3 app I have a  few conditional elements in the controller. for example I have a number say "10" which has met the model state requirements but I have a if statement that checks if the number "10" exists in another table. Should it exist the data is submited but should it not exist I return the view and would like to return a error message.

My question is what would be the best way of displaying a error in this situation. I have looked at returning a viewbag message but I would like to style the error message with a box and by adding this style to the view it always gets displayed which is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the error message to the modelstate:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("somekey", "some error message");
```

and inside your view display error messages using the validation summary helper:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

You could of course add a string property to your view model and set its value in case of error. Then inside the view check whether the model property has a value and if it does display the error messages inside a custom styled element. It seems a bit like a wheel reinvention assuming you could simply append the error message to the modelstate but worth mentioning.

Comment: If this was on a post action how could you retain the posted data and return the completed form?

Comment: @Sparkle, you would pass the same view model when returning the view as the one your POST controller action took from the view as parameter.

Comment: That work fantastically! Words of wisdom that saved me hours thanks!